# How to generate URL with Slug and query string in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I would like to generate a path in controller with a pattern like this -

```
mysite.com/slug?param=123
```

At the Moment I am doing this -

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_slug',array('page_slug'=>'my_slug')));
```

I would like to append a query param to this url. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add param name and value to the array:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_slug',array('page_slug'=>'my_slug', 'param' => '123')));
```

It is described in the Book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings ("if you pass extra ones, they will be added to the URI as a query string")